# extra columns in model association sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

How can I have an extra column in postgres with sailsjs model association?

This is an example of my two models

```
// Users.js attribute
...
challenges: {
  collection: 'challenge',
  via: 'userChallenge'
}


// Challenge.js attribute
...
userChallenge: {
  collection: 'users',
  via: 'challenges'
}
...
```

With this I get the table association (many to many)

```
 id | challenge_userChallenge | users_challenges
```

I need one or more extra columns like "active" or something like that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just add the new column in your model? It is not clear what do you intend to do by adding other column. Are you trying to make a composite key for the relationship?

Comment: @E.Celis my intention is to have an extra column in a many to many relation table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [through associations](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations).

> Many-to-Many through associations behave the same way as many-to-many
>   associations with the exception of the join table being automatically
>   created for you. In a Many-To-Many through assocation you define a
>   model containing two fields that correspond to the two models you will
>   be joining together. When defining an association you will add the
>   through key to show that the model should be used rather than the
>   automatic join table.

Let's take the `Post` and `Tag` models as an example. The `Post` has and belongs to many `Tag` and the `Tag` has and belongs to many `Post`. These two models will be joined via the `PostTag` model.

Our `Post` model:

```
/**
 * Post.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  tableName: 'posts',

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    // Many to many: Post has and belongs to many Tag.
    tags: {
      collection: 'Tag',
      via: 'postId',
      through: 'PostTag'
    }

};
```

Our `Tag` model:

```
/**
 * Tag.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  tableName: 'tags',

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },

    // Many to many: Tag has and belongs to many Post.
    posts: {
      collection: 'Post',
      via: 'tagId',
      through: 'PostTag'
    }

  }

};
```

Our `PostTag` model (we're creating it manually, we don't want Sails.js to create it automatically):

```
/**
 * PostTag.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  tableName: 'posts_tags',

  attributes: {

    postId: {
      model: 'Post'
    },

    tagId: {
      model: 'Tag'
    }

  }

};
```

The `PostTag` model is actually the join table. In this model, you can define your extra fields.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50437361/5097467) by Vladyslav Turak is **correct for Sails v1.0** and up, please note that [Through Associations](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations) are **NOT SUPPORTED** in **Sails 0.12**.

To achieve the similar effect with **Sails 0.12**, you can use the following:

The `Post` model:

```
/**
 * Post.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    // Many to many: Post has and belongs to many PostTag.
    tags: {
      collection: 'PostTag',
      via: 'post'
    }

};
```

The `Tag` model:

```
/**
 * Tag.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },

    // Many to many: Tag has and belongs to many PostTag.
    posts: {
      collection: 'PostTag',
      via: 'tag',
    }

  }

};
```

Our `PostTag` model (we're creating it manually, we don't want Sails.js to create it automatically):

```
/**
 * PostTag.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    post: {
      model: 'Post'
    },

    tag: {
      model: 'Tag'
    },

    customField: {
      type: 'string'
    }

  }

};
```

The `PostTag` model is actually the join table. In this model, you can define your extra fields.

Hope this helps someone using **Sails v0.12**.